# MySQL - Subtract previous day data from current day data, with special conditions

Tags: mysql

I have the following example data:

```
  ID | DATE  | LOCATION | DATA 
 ----|-------|----------|------ 
   1 | MAR-1 |        1 |  100 
   2 | MAR-2 |        1 |  120 
   3 | MAR-3 |        1 |  160 
   4 | MAR-3 |        2 |   80 
   5 | MAR-4 |        1 |  170 
   6 | MAR-4 |        2 |  100 
   7 | MAR-5 |        1 |   10 
   8 | MAR-6 |        1 |   50
```

I need to subtract the previous day's data from the current day's and put the result into a "delta" column, where the result is also unique per location. In this example, the data is from a power meter, which is reset to zero periodically. So, I need to test if the "delta" result is negative, and if so, copy only the raw "data" value in the "delta" column. Based on the above example data, I would like this output:

```
  ID | DATE  | LOCATION | DATA | DELTA |            COMMENT            
 ----|-------|----------|------|-------|------------------------------- 
   1 | MAR-1 |        1 |  100 | NULL  | NO PREVIOUS DATA EXISTS       
   2 | MAR-2 |        1 |  120 | 20    |                               
   3 | MAR-3 |        1 |  160 | 40    |                               
   4 | MAR-3 |        2 |   80 | NULL  | NO PREVIOUS DATA EXISTS       
   5 | MAR-4 |        1 |  170 | 10    |                               
   6 | MAR-4 |        2 |  100 | 20    |                               
   7 | MAR-5 |        1 |   10 | 10    | DELTA WOULD BE - SO TAKE DATA 
   8 | MAR-6 |        1 |   50 | 40    |
```

I'm using MySQL v5.7.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subquery to find the output like following.

```
SELECT id,date,location,data, 
       CASE 
         WHEN nv < 0 THEN data 
         ELSE nv 
       END AS Delta 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               data - (SELECT  data 
                       FROM   mytable t1 
                       WHERE  t1.id < t2.id 
                              AND t1.location = t2.location 
                       ORDER  BY id DESC
                       limit 1)nv 
        FROM   mytable t2) t
```

[**Online Demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m1HhFWFX2zC6BEjN1939rk/1)

**Output**

```
| id  | date  | location | data | Delta |
| --- | ----- | -------- | ---- | ----- |
| 1   | MAR-1 | 1        | 100  |       |
| 2   | MAR-2 | 1        | 120  | 20    |
| 3   | MAR-3 | 1        | 160  | 40    |
| 4   | MAR-3 | 2        | 80   |       |
| 5   | MAR-4 | 1        | 170  | 10    |
| 6   | MAR-4 | 2        | 100  | 20    |
| 7   | MAR-5 | 1        | 10   | 10    |
| 8   | MAR-6 | 1        | 50   | 40    |
```

Comment: This was the perfect solution.  I just had to modify it to use my date timestamp instead of the id.  Thank you!!!